# Rotate xticklabels in seaborn clutstermap

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to rotate my xticklabels in a seaborn cluster map and I've tried solutions from other posts but I can never get it to work. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
hm=sns.clustermap(data=pltdf.iloc()[:,1:14],
              standard_scale=0,
               yticklabels=pltdf['uniprot_sym'])
hm.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-05bb29d461e2> in <module>
      2               standard_scale=0,
      3                yticklabels=pltdf['uniprot_sym'])
----> 4 hm.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
      5 

AttributeError: 'ClusterGrid' object has no attribute 'set_xticklabels'
```

and this

```
hm=sns.clustermap(data=pltdf.iloc()[:,1:14],
              standard_scale=0,
               yticklabels=pltdf['uniprot_sym'])
for ax in hm.axes.flat:
    ax.tick_params("x", labelrotation=45)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-d96774d92376> in <module>
      2               standard_scale=0,
      3                yticklabels=pltdf['uniprot_sym'])
----> 4 for ax in hm.axes.flat:
      5     ax.tick_params("x", labelrotation=45)

AttributeError: 'ClusterGrid' object has no attribute 'axes'
```

Both output this[image]

Comment: I was using 0.11.0, and updated to 0.11.1, but still got the same. The answer below did work though.

Answer (score 2):

```
hm=sns.clustermap(data=pltdf.iloc()[:,1:14],
                  standard_scale=0,
                  yticklabels=pltdf['uniprot_sym'])
plt.setp(hm.ax_heatmap.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```